# What does the phrase, “lack pretense of fairness” mean?

Tags: meaning, word-usage

White House counsel wrote to House speaker a letter on October 8th refusing to cooperate with House’s impeachment inquiry into President Trump’s dealing with Ukraine, that reads:

> “Given that your inquiry *lacks* any legitimate constitutional
>   foundation, *any pretense of fairness* or even the most elementary due
>   process protections, the Executive Branch cannot be expected to
>   participate in it.” – The Hill Oct. 9

It seems to me the word, “pretense” being used here in different manner from usual usage as defined in dictionaries at hand;

- A way of behaving that is intended to deceive people – Cambridge Dictionary
- A claim, esp, an unsupported one as to some distinction or accomplishment, pretention – Collins dictionary
- The act of behaving in a particular way, in order to make other people believe sth that is not true. - Oxford Advanced Learner's Dictionary

And it sounds like something like “rules” rather than 'pretension' and 'deception.'

What does “pretense” in the above sentence mean?

Comment: In colloquial speech, when one says there isn't even a "pretense" of some (presumably positive) behavior, it implies that evidence of the desirable behavior is completely lacking.  Of course, in this case the pot is calling the kettle black.

Answer (score 1):

It means, it’s not even trying to be fair.

It means it is blatantly unfair, the unfairness showing itself openly with absolutely no effort to hide it - with no effort to use pretense, which is an aspect of diplomacy or tact, to cover it up.

Definition:

An attempt to make something that is not the case appear true.

"his smile is a pretense that masks his hidden anger"

https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/pretence